# ConcurrentModificationException thrown by sublist

Tags: java, list

I have very simple code:

```
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    String a = "a";
    String b = "b";
    String c = "c";
    String d = "d";

    list.add(a);
    list.add(b);
    list.add(c);

    List<String> backedList = list.subList(0, 2);
    list.add(0, d); 
    System.out.println("2b: " + backedList);
```

And I get ConcurrentModificationException exception by list.add(0, d). So in general, it's because of sublist(). I'm very confused, because in case of sublist() the documentation says:

> The returned list is backed by this list, so non-structural changes in
>   the returned list are reflected in this list, and **vice-versa**.

Could you explain me where the catch is?

Comment: The "catch" is that adding an element to a list is a **structural** change.

Comment: the vice-versa in that sentence is misleading as you mention @peter, because as the docs (and your code), explain later, modifying the backed list without going through the sublist will raise a ConcurrentModificationException

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `subList` is simple a view of the original list (see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList%28int,%20int%29)).  You are allowed to mutate elements within it but not change the structure of the list.

According to the documentation, `subList` behaviour is undefined if you try to make structural changes.  I guess in this particular implementation, `ConcurrentModificationException` was decided as the undefined behaviour.

> The semantics of the list returned by this method become undefined if the backing list (i.e., this list) is structurally modified in any way other than via the returned list. (Structural modifications are those that change the size of this list, or otherwise perturb it in such a fashion that iterations in progress may yield incorrect results.)

Comment: I wasted a day to check what exactly went wrong, Thanks this helped me rearranging the line in my code

Comment: Please see answer i added below for more clarification of above comment

Answer (score 7):

> The returned list is backed by this list, so **non-structural** changes in the returned list are reflected in this list, and vice-versa. [Reference Link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-)

Above statement is absolutely correct but we have to keep in mind **non-structural** change. I would like to depict two examples justifying above statement.
**Example-1:** Performing **Non-Structural** change in **list**.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> listArr = new ArrayList<>();
        listArr.add("Delhi");
        listArr.add("Bangalore");
        listArr.add("New York");
        listArr.add("London");

        List<String> listArrSub = listArr.subList(1, 3);

        System.out.println("List-: " + listArr);
        System.out.println("Sub List-: " + listArrSub);

        //Performing Non-Structural Change in list.
        Collections.swap(listArr, 0, 1);

        System.out.println("\nAfter Non-Structural Change...\n");

        System.out.println("List-: " + listArr);
        System.out.println("Sub List-: " + listArrSub);
    }
```

Output-:

```
List-: [Delhi, Bangalore, New York, London]
Sub List-: [Bangalore, New York]

After Non-Structural Change...

List-: [Bangalore, Delhi, New York, London]
Sub List-: [Delhi, New York]
```

Explanation-: As per aforementioned Oracle's documentation statement, swapping operation is reflected in both the lists.

**Example-2:** Performing **Non-Structural** change in **sub list**.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> listArr = new ArrayList<>();
        listArr.add("Delhi");
        listArr.add("Bangalore");
        listArr.add("New York");
        listArr.add("London");

        List<String> listArrSub = listArr.subList(1, 3);

        System.out.println("List-: " + listArr);
        System.out.println("Sub List-: " + listArrSub);

        //Performing Non-Structural Change in sub list.
        Collections.swap(listArrSub, 0, 1);

        System.out.println("\nAfter Non-Structural Change...\n");

        System.out.println("List-: " + listArr);
        System.out.println("Sub List-: " + listArrSub);
    }
```

Output-:

```
List-: [Delhi, Bangalore, New York, London]
Sub List-: [Bangalore, New York]

After Non-Structural Change...

List-: [Delhi, New York, Bangalore, London]
Sub List-: [New York, Bangalore]
```

Explanation-:As per aforementioned Oracle's documentation statement, swapping operation is reflected in both the lists however it has been performed on sub list.

As we have seen **Non-Structural** changes in the aforementioned two examples. Now let's see **Structural** changes as per below statement which is given in the Oracle's documentation.

> The semantics of the list returned by this method become undefined if the backing list (i.e., this list) is structurally modified in any way other than via the returned list. (Structural modifications are those that change the size of this list, or otherwise perturb it in such a fashion that iterations in progress may yield incorrect results.)

**Example-3:** Performing **Structural** change in list.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> listArr = new ArrayList<>();
        listArr.add("Delhi");
        listArr.add("Bangalore");
        listArr.add("New York");
        listArr.add("London");

        List<String> listArrSub = listArr.subList(1, 3);

        System.out.println("List-: " + listArr);
        System.out.println("Sub List-: " + listArrSub);

        //Performing Structural Change in list.
        listArr.add("Mumbai");

        System.out.println("\nAfter Structural Change...\n");

        System.out.println("List-: " + listArr);
        System.out.println("Sub List-: " + listArrSub);
    }
```

Output-:

```
List-: [Delhi, Bangalore, New York, London]
Sub List-: [Bangalore, New York]

After Structural Change...

List-: [Delhi, Bangalore, New York, London, Mumbai]
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$SubList.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:1231)
    at java.util.ArrayList$SubList.listIterator(ArrayList.java:1091)
    at java.util.AbstractList.listIterator(AbstractList.java:299)
    at java.util.ArrayList$SubList.iterator(ArrayList.java:1087)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:454)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2982)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at infosys.Research.main(Research.java:26)
```

Explanation-:As per aforementioned Oracle's documentation statement, structural modification operation is throwing `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` exception whenever **The semantics of the list returned by this method become undefined if the backing list (i.e., this list) is structurally modified in any way other than via the returned list.**

**Example-4:** Performing **Structural** change in **sub list**.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> listArr = new ArrayList<>();
        listArr.add("Delhi");
        listArr.add("Bangalore");
        listArr.add("New York");
        listArr.add("London");

        List<String> listArrSub = listArr.subList(1, 3);

        System.out.println("List-: " + listArr);
        System.out.println("Sub List-: " + listArrSub);

        //Performing Structural Change in sub list.
        listArrSub.add("Mumbai");

        System.out.println("\nAfter Structural Change...\n");

        System.out.println("List-: " + listArr);
        System.out.println("Sub List-: " + listArrSub);
    }
```

Output-:

```
List-: [Delhi, Bangalore, New York, London]
Sub List-: [Bangalore, New York]

After Structural Change...

List-: [Delhi, Bangalore, New York, Mumbai, London]
Sub List-: [Bangalore, New York, Mumbai]
```

Explanation-: **Structural modification** to returned list is working well and reflecting in the list altogether.

Answer (score 0):

list.add(0, d) involves moving all items by one position and increasing list's size. It's quite structural change.

Answer (score 0):

**Scenario in which this error was encountered**

- I had a list(original list) with let's say 100 item
- Sort original list in ascending order
- Sublist it -> created sublist (ascending ordered sublist)
- Sort original list in descending order
- Iterate over sublist(ascending ordered sublist) list

**Got concurrent modification exception**

**Fix to above scenario**

- I had a list(original list) with let's say 100 item
- Sort it in ascending order
- Sublist it -> created sublist (ascending ordered sublist)
- Iterate over sublisted(ascending ordered sublist) list
- Sort original list in descending order