# adding sublist into guava table in nested loop gives concurrentmodificationerror

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, multidimensional-array, guava

There is multidimensional array. I am traversing this array. While traversing I am generating random values and adding into one list in 3rd for loop. After that I am adding each sublist of list into guava table. The first piece of code(there are 3 for loops )running without error. But when I try to print all table I am receiving troublesome error. I can not solve this problem for two days. What can I do?

```
Table<Integer, Integer, List> paymentAmounts = HashBasedTable.create();
List<Integer> amounts = new ArrayList<Integer>();
int count_begin = 0; //list size
for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
        if(i != j){
            for(int a=0; a<banksNumberOfOrders[i][j]; a++){         
                int amount = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(begin1, end1);
                amounts.add(amount);
            }   
            int count_end = count_begin+banksNumberOfOrders[i][j];          
            paymentAmounts.put(i,j,amounts.subList(count_begin, count_end));
            count_begin = count_end;
            System.out.println(i+" --> "+j+" "+paymentAmounts.get(i, j)+" ");
        }   
    }       
    System.out.println();
}

System.out.println(paymentAmounts.cellSet()); //gives concurrent modification error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
paymentAmounts.put(i,j,amounts.subList(count_begin, count_end));
```

to

```
paymentAmounts.put(i,j,new ArrayList<>(amounts.subList(count_begin, count_end)));
```

You are otherwise inserting just "views" (not copies) of the original `amounts` list and that causes issues since you are modifying the `amounts` list after you made that view.

Same issue as in [ConcurrentModificationException thrown by sublist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8817608/concurrentmodificationexception-thrown-by-sublist)