# Why does List.addAll of a reversed subList of the list cause a ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, concurrentmodification

I've been trying to take a [sub list](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#subList(int,int)) of a list, reverse it, and place the [reversed](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#reverse(java.util.List)) list back into the starting position. For example, say we have the list `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`, then reversing from index 2 to index 4 would give `[1, 2, 5, 4, 3, 6]`.

I've written some code for this, however it gives a `ConcurrentModificationException` every time (unless startIndex == endIndex). A minimum reproducible example is provided below:

```
int startIndex = 2;
int endIndex = 4;
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(1);
list.add(2);
list.add(3);
list.add(4);
list.add(5);
list.add(6);

List<Integer> toReverse = list.subList(startIndex, endIndex+1);
Collections.reverse(toReverse);
list.removeAll(toReverse);
list.addAll(startIndex, toReverse);
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
>     at java.util.ArrayList$SubList.checkForComodification(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.ArrayList$SubList.size(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.AbstractCollection.toArray(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.util.ArrayList.addAll(Unknown Source)    at
>   test.ConcurrentExample.main(ConcurrentExample.java:64)

The actual line the error refers to is `list.addAll(startIndex, toReverse);`.

I'm not sure what the issue is as nothing appears to be getting changed while being iterated over. If anyone could explain *why* this is happening and/or *how* to fix it, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @pvpkiran I don't think that's my issue. I don't explicitly use any iterator (although I'm sure `reverse` implicitly uses one to reverse the order). Any changes that are being made happen *after* each step has ended (as in, not during iteration)

Comment: error is accord because of this line :- list.removeAll(toReverse); . In debugger see the value of reverse

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602636/why-is-a-concurrentmodificationexception-thrown-and-how-to-debug-it

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8817608/concurrentmodificationexception-thrown-by-sublist

Comment: Are you aware that `subList` returns a *view* into the original list? When you did `Collections.reverse(toReverse);`, you already modified the original list; the subsequent `list.removeAll(toReverse); list.addAll(startIndex, toReverse);` are entirely obsolete.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

List.subList returns a live view of the list between the specified elements, not a copy of those elements (see [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-)), therefore adding to the original list will also modify the sublist, which will lead to `ConcurrentModificationException` (since what is being added and to what you add to also are modified at the same time).

```
list.subList(startIndex, endIndex+1)
```

You can fix a code by copying the list, like

```
List<Integer> toReverse = new ArrayList<>(list.subList(startIndex, endIndex+1));
```

Comment: There is no need for the copy. As you said yourself, the sublist is a view, so after `Collections.reverse(toReverse);`, the original list has been modified already, so the simple fix is to remove the obsolete `list.removeAll(toReverse); list.addAll(startIndex, toReverse);` statements.

Answer (score 5):

from the documentation of [ArrayList.subList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#subList(int,%20int)) :

> The returned list is backed by this list, so non-structural changes in
>   the returned list are reflected in this list, and vice-versa

So when you try to add items at the index of the subList 'view', it creates concurrent modification.

Answer (score 2):

Issue lies here at `ArrayList#checkForComodification`

```
private void checkForComodification() {
    if (ArrayList.this.modCount != this.modCount)
        throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
    }
}
```

However in this particular case you don't need to manually re-add reversed sublist, since the reversion is performed on the **original** list. So all you need is just to drop

```
list.removeAll(...);
list.addAll(...);
```

and leave only this code:

```
List<Integer> toReverse = list.subList(startIndex, endIndex+1);
Collections.reverse(toReverse);
```

Answer (score 0):

From suggestions of **helospark** & **Nir Levy**, use [skip & limit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#skip-long-) in Stream

```
List<Integer> toReverse = list.stream() //
                .skip(startIndex) //
                .limit(endIndex + 1) //
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```